# Error "SSIS script task is corrupted" while executing the package on command prompt

Tags: mysql, ssis

I am upgrading a SQL server 2014 to 2019 and as a part of this I am migrating my SSIS packages also to latest version (VS2019, SQL server untegration services projects version 3.2.2).

**The problem:** When I am running my updated SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) packages via Visual Studio or SQL Server Agent job it succeeds, but when I am running this via command prompt (the task scheduler job), if my job contains any script task involved it failing with below error.

> Script task is corrupted.

Things I already have taken care of:

1. I changed the delay validation to true.
2. Targeted version of SQL server is available is the server.

Comment: To get better answers we need to see what yo have tried and where it has failed. Show us the script task that is failing. Please see this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question so you get better answers.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I edited your question a bit to increase readability, please check whether I misunderstood stuff.